# Can two different users access same database table for inserting different data?

Tags: c#, mysql, foreign-keys

My question is related to my final year project. In which two users of two different pharmacy will add their data into same database table. I want to ask that how these users login in such a way that they can insert data in table separately and data will be show separately.

In short how same database table will store data of both users separately? Is it can be done by using some foreign keys or by any conditions for user in c# code?

Comment: Please provide some sample data and your desired output. (See [How to
format SQL tables in a Stack Overflow
post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96125) for how to add some.) Additional schema
information and where your attempts failed would also help us to help you better.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it quite easily.
let them login through their username and in database you create a column as username. So when one user stores data then every time he will also be storing his username in the database and similarly for the other user as well.I am just giving username column as an example.You can define any column as a differentiator for the two users.
So when you display the data to the users use that column value and display only those rows which are specific to that column.

Answer (score 0):

YES ! There are several ways but as your answer don't have a specific example of what you want, you can have two different tables for respective pharmacy so their data will be saved separately in the same database.
At the time of retrieval of data you can target these two tables respectively for each pharmacy. This will avoid the logic for retrieving data of two different pharmacies from same table.